# Sublime Text 3: Format HTML, some tags in one line

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Ok, my situation is a bit different than all the threads here about formatting HTML. Also, I've installed about every HTML formatting plugin out there with mixed results and none really solve my issue.

Also, configuring these plugins can be difficult since I'm not a programmer and some authors don't provide enough information to customize their plugins.

And I want some plugin or something because there is a lot of code in separate files.

I have some trouble with whitespaces so I want to change code format like;

All I want to do is turn this markup:

```
<p>
   <span>
     item here
   </span>
   <span>
     item here
   </span>
   <span>
     item here
   </span>
</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>
   <span>item here</span>
   <span>item here</span>
   <span>item here</span>
</p>
```

Is there any one who knows how to fix it in sublime text 3? Thanks.

Comment: `ctrl + j` to remove all line breaks in selected chunk then you can find and insert line breaks `\n` after `</span>`.

Comment: Try a regex like `(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|<p>)\s*<span>\K\s*((?:(?!<(?:p|/?span)>).)*?)\s*(</span>)` -> `$1$2`